# how to change the format of date value from rails hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a Variable

```
values = []
records.map { |record|
  # record <Letter::History Letter_ID: 15, Asset_Code: "10042019/01/01", Frequency_Code: "Alpha", Due_Date: "2014-05-29">
  # record.attributes => {"Letter_ID"=>15,
                        # "Code"=>"10018001/01/01",
                        # "Frequency_Code"=>"Alpha",
                        # "Due_Date"=>Sat, 24 May 2014
                        # }
  values << record.attributes
}
```

I want to change the date format of `Due_Date` to `2014-05-24`

I have another set of `hash` that returns

```
second_hash = {"Letter_ID"=>15, 
     "Code"=>"10018001/01/01",
      "Frequency_Code"=>"Alpha",
      "Due_Date"=>Sat, 24 May 2014
     }
```

So I can compare the two `hash` value like

```
values.to_a == second_hash.to_a
```

Because of the `Due_date` format it `returns` `false` now.

Thanks

Comment: @caryswoveland Thanks. I just give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using methods from the class [Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) or the method [String#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) with a regular expression.

**Using `Date` class methods**

```
my_hash = {"Letter_ID"     =>15,
           "Code"          =>"10018001/01/01",
           "Frequency_Code"=>"Alpha",
           "Due_Date"      =>"Sat, 24 May 2014",
           "Sent_Date"     =>"Thu, 12 Mar 2015"}

require 'date'

my_hash["Due_Date"] = Date.parse(my_hash["Due_Date"]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  #=> "2014-05-24" 

my_hash
  #=> {"Letter_ID"=>15, "Code"=>"10018001/01/01", "Frequency_Code"=>"Alpha",
  #    "Due_Date"=>"2014-05-24", "Sent_Date"=>"Thu, 12 Mar 2015"}
```

Here we first use the class method [Date::parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) to convert the existing date string to a date object:

```
date_obj = Date.parse(my_hash["Due_Date"])
  #=> Date.parse("Sat, 24 May 2014")
  #=> #<Date: 2014-05-24 ((2456802j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Now use [Date#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) to set the value of `"Due_Date"` to `date_obj` converted to the desired format:

```
my_hash["Due_Date"] = date_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  #=> "2014-05-24"
```

If you wish to demand that the value of the `"Due_Date"` conforms to a given string format, use [Date#strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) instead of `parse`:

```
date_obj = Date.strptime(my_hash["Due_Date"], '%a, %d %b %Y')
  #=> #<Date: 2014-05-24 ((2456802j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

This approach "mutates" (alter) `my_hash`. If instead we wish to return a new hash, leaving `my_hash` unchanged, operate on a copy of `my_hash` (`my_hash.dup`).

**Using `String#sub`**

First define a hash to convert month abbreviations to string representations of digits, padded with leading zeros where necessary:

```
h = %w[Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec].
      zip(('01'..'12').to_a).to_h
  #=> {"Jan"=>"01", "Feb"=>"02", "Mar"=>"03", "Apr"=>"04",
  #    "May"=>"05", "Jun"=>"06", "Jul"=>"07", "Aug"=>"08",
  #    "Sep"=>"09", "Oct"=>"10", "Nov"=>"11", "Dec"=>"12"}
```

We will use this regular expression, which has three capture groups, for day, month and year:

```
r = /\D*(\d{2}) ([A-Z][a-z]{2}) (\d{4})/
```

Because `sub` must evaluate the hash `h` in order to convert the month from (here) "May" to "05", we must use the form of `sub` that employs a hash to compute the replacement string:

```
my_hash["Due_Date"] = my_hash["Due_Date"].sub(r) { "#{$3}-#{h[$2]}-#{$1}" }
  #=> "2014-05-24"
```

To use named groups (v1.9+), you could do this:

```
r = /\D*(?<day>\d{2}) (?<mon>[A-Z][a-z]{2}) (?<yr>\d{4})/

my_hash["Due_Date"].sub(r) do
  day = Regexp.last_match(:day)    #=> "24"
  mon = h[Regexp.last_match(:mon)] #=> "05"
  yr  = Regexp.last_match(:yr)     #=> "2014"
  "#{yr}-#{mon}-#{day}"
end
  #=> "2014-05-24"
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. I tried in the console and it worked perfectly. But When I raise at the code and the page returns, `exception class/object expected`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. It makes me to understand clearly the process now.

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
DateTime.parse(my_hash["Due_Date"]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But I got an error message `undefined method 'gsub!' for Thu, 29 May 2014:Date`

Comment: post the question properly

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
my_hash["Due_Date"] = my_hash["Due_Date"].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Thanks. But It seems it doesn't update the values. In the database the date format is correct. But When It comes to hash, its changed automatically. How can I update this before I push to some variable.

Comment: `strftime` is not a method of `String`. Also, that is not the correct date format. Please test before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that strftime() would have proved suitable for such a job, and that parameter %F would be correct as it returns the extended calendar date.

```
my_hash["Due_Date"].strftime(%F)
```

See http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime